# creating nested associative array from json code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating an associative array from a json code so that i can use in my curl code that connects to an API.  Now it seems like the associative array outputted is incorrect. I would like to format it correctly, but now I get message an error saying the array is incorrect.

The json code:

```
{
"payment": [
    {
        "clientCorrelator": "54321",
        "endUserId": "tel:+16309700001",
        "merchantCode": "01234",
        "merchantPin": "1234",
        "merchantNumber": "tel:+16309700001",
        "notifyURL": "http://example.com/notifyURL",


        "paymentAmount": {
            "chargingInformation": [
                {
                    "amount": "10",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "description": "AlienInvadersGame"
                }
            ],
            "chargingMetaData": [
                {
                    "onBehalfOf": "Example Games Inc",
                    "purchaseCategoryCode": "Game",
                    "channel": "WAP",
                    "taxAmount": "0"
                }
            ],
            "referenceCode": "REF-12345",
            "transactionOperationStatus": "Charged"
        }
    }
]


}
```

The php code to build the array:

```
jasondata = file_get_contents("payment.json");
$json = json_decode($jasondata, true);
$payment = ($json['payment']) ;

print_r($payment);
```

The output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [clientCorrelator] => 54321 [endUserId] => tel:+16309700001 [merchantCode] => 01234 [merchantPin] => 1234 [merchantNumber] => tel:+16309700001 [notifyURL] => http://example.com/notifyURL [paymentAmount] => Array ( [chargingInformation] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 10 [currency] => USD [description] => AlienInvadersGame ) ) [chargingMetaData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [onBehalfOf] => Example Games Inc [purchaseCategoryCode] => Game [channel] => WAP [taxAmount] => 0 ) ) [referenceCode] => REF-12345 [transactionOperationStatus] => Charged ) ) )
```

My main goal is to remove the [0] indexes without messing up the array. please assist

Comment: You can't, since `'payment'` is an array of objects. the `0` is necessary in php - array entries MUST have keys.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn only got rid of the first [0] zero index, thanks. any idea how to get rid of the rest of them ?

Comment: @kya https://eval.in/399423 But if you exactly know that all arrays have only one Item

Comment: @splash58 Yes, each array has exactly one item

Comment: @kya then look the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more or less safe function

```
$payment = json_decode($str, true);

function RemoveZeroIndex(&$arr) {
  foreach($arr as $key => &$item) {       // walk array
     if (is_array($item) &&               // if array
        (count($item) === 1) &&           // with one item
        isset($item[0]))                  // and numeric index
            $item = $item[0];             // shift it
     if (is_array($item)) 
        RemoveZeroIndex($item);           // call recursively
   }
}

RemoveZeroIndex($payment);
print_r($payment);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `$payment = ($json['payment']);`

change that to `$payment = reset($json['payment']);`

However if there are multiple entries under `payment`, then you should just loop over them like:

```
foreach($json['payment'] as $payment){
    print_r($payment);
}
```

The loop also would work if there was any number of elements under `payment`, so not just multiple.

Comment: it worked for the first [0] zero index, but not for nested zero indexes

Comment: @kya `reset` will only get the first index. If you have more you would want to loop over them or you would  need to set them each to a different variable. There is no way to get rid of the numbers otherwise. Even in javascript/json, you don't see the numbers, but javascript will add them when parsing the json into an object in script.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jonathan Khun.

For your nested arrays you just do the same. Reset the internal pointer of that array.

```
<?php

$jasondata = '{
"payment": [
    {
        "clientCorrelator": "54321",
        "endUserId": "tel:+16309700001",
        "merchantCode": "01234",
        "merchantPin": "1234",
        "merchantNumber": "tel:+16309700001",
        "notifyURL": "http://example.com/notifyURL",


        "paymentAmount": {
            "chargingInformation": [
                {
                    "amount": "10",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "description": "AlienInvadersGame"
                }
            ],
            "chargingMetaData": [
                {
                    "onBehalfOf": "Example Games Inc",
                    "purchaseCategoryCode": "Game",
                    "channel": "WAP",
                    "taxAmount": "0"
                }
            ],
            "referenceCode": "REF-12345",
            "transactionOperationStatus": "Charged"
        }
    }
]


}';

$json = json_decode($jasondata, true);
$payment = reset($json['payment']);
$payment['paymentAmount']['chargingInformation'] = reset($payment['paymentAmount']['chargingInformation']);
$payment['paymentAmount']['chargingMetaData'] = reset($payment['paymentAmount']['chargingMetaData']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($payment);
?>
```